# Public transport from Nantes to La Roche-Bernard

Tags: public-transport, france, transportation

I'm heading to a wedding in La Roche-Bernard on June. I want to know how easy it would be for me to arrive in Nantes and get public transport there. I speak no French but am generally comfortable bumbling around and miming my way through things.

Answer (score 3):

Getting to La Roche-Bernard from Nantes is not easy. On this [map](http://www.morbihan.fr/UserFile/Flash/CarteTIM/carte_cg56.swf) of the region around La Roche-Bernard you can see that there is two bus lines going there. So you're alternatives are:

- Get a train to Vannes (1h10 to 2h) and take [bus 8](http://www.keolis-atlantique.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/BAT-L8-int-hiver-20141.pdf) to La Roche-Bernard (1 hour). This bus only runs Mo-Fr for some connections (LMMeJV) and Mo-Sa for others (LMMeJVS), there's no connections on Sundays and you'll have to call them the day before for the bus to run all the way to La Roche-Bernard. Also note that the timetable is the Winter timetable, so you should check closer to the date again.
- Get a train to Redon (40 min to 1h) and take [bus 10](http://maury-transports.com/usermedia/int-L10-Hiver%20copie.pdf) circuit 2 (45 min). This bus will only run Mo-Fr and different days have different timings. Again this is the Winter timetable.

Getting to Vannes or Redon from Nantes shouldn't be a problem and you can check the train timings on the site of the [SNCF](http://www.sncf.com/en/passengers).

Comment: it would be nice if you could give a rough idea of the time it takes (as the train to Redon already takes 50 mins, I suppose this would take 2-3 hours)

Comment: This seems like a perfectly reasonably answer, but I'll just give it a little while... Basically it looks hard.